# Using iPad2 Charger to Charge iPhone5S

Tags: iphone, charger

I just bought iPhone5S. While I need converter to use iPhone5S charger, instead I am using an iPad2 charger.

Is it OK if I do that? What's the different (in terms of voltage, ampere, and so on) of iPad2 and iPhone5S charger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from Apple's product page for the [12W USB Power Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD836LL/A/apple-12w-usb-power-adapter), it's compatible with iPhone 5S. The output voltage is the same in both, except the 12W adapter gives a higher amperage (2.4A instead of 1A), but your phone can regulate it's intake.

I use my iPad Air's charger occasionally with my iPhone 5S with no problems.